# How to do "read more or read less" concept for tinymce Editor content in Laravel blade file

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

i am using a **tinymce editor** for inserting content into the database which stores the data along with the html tags and i want to add ***read more or read less*** concept to Laravel blade file. is any methods or technique is there in Laravel 8.

I have tried `{!! Str::words($value->blog_content, 8, ' readmore >>>') !!}` but it doesn't consider the html tags, so UI was collapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [strip the tags](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php) before call the words function

```php
{!! Str::words(strip_tags($value->blog_content), 8, ' readmore >>>') !!}
```